# "View private files" permission not effective

Tags: users, files

I have 3 users, an **administrator**, an **uploader**, and a **viewer**. The uploader has a file field attached to his profile and the destination folder of the uploaded (in my case .pdf) file is set to the private directory.

The administrator can certainly view *all* files and when I enter the absolute URL of the private file (MySite.com/system/files/File.pdf), it gets displayed on my screen as expected.

I want the viewer to be able to view *all* files as well, while not having all the permissions that an administrator would have. Hence, I gave the viewer permission to "View private files" and to "Document: Download any files" (I am running File Entity 7.x-2.0-alpha3+30-dev, which gives me these options). However, when I enter the absolute URL of the private file while being logged in as the viewer, I get an "Access denied" error.

Can anyone confirm this issue and advise me how to resolve it?

Comment: What happens when you give the viewer "View user profiles" permissions?

Comment: I just tested this, but unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: May be "Accessing Private Files" section in https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/file would help.

Comment: Perhaps related https://www.drupal.org/node/2351691